# Normal maps in node editor cause a blue/black tinge

Tags: node-editor

So, I'm guessing this ties into the Vertex paint? I created a mix shader node with two principled shaders, skinlike ya know? One being more red/pink than the other. ANYWAYS. I created a Col attribute with both shaders and painted where I wanted the more red areas to be (In this case it would be the lips and spots on the face). I continued to plug this attribute into the mix shader Fac input.

After doing this, no matter what, both displacement and normal maps are absolutely a pain in the ass because they leave this odd discoloration. If anyone can figure how I can get around this, I would be so happy[image]

[image]

Comment: So does it render properly with 1 principled shader? Can we see your normal map texture?

Comment: I'm not seeing the difference. Can you circle the rendered object too?